# Posts from all the categories are being displayed instead of particular category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

Created a custom post type `Menu` it has `Categories` and `Sub-Categories`.

I am succeeded in fetching Sub-Categories of the post using this code.

```
<?php
    $wcatTerms = get_terms('menu-items', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC',  'parent' =>0));
    foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
        //echo $wcatTerm->name;
        $wsubargs = array('hierarchical'=>1,'show_option_none'=>'','hide_empty'=>0,'parent'=>$wcatTerm->term_id,'taxonomy'=>'menu-items');
        $wsubcats = get_categories($wsubargs);
        foreach ($wsubcats as $wsc):
           $childcat = $wsc->name; ?>
            <h2><?php echo $childcat; ?></h2>

        endforeach;
    endforeach;
```

Later as per my requirement I want to displayed post based in `sub-category` for that I used this `query`

```
<?php 
        $posts = get_posts(array(
              'post_type' => 'menu',
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'order' =>  'DESC',
              'taxonomy' => $wcatTerm->taxonomy,
              'term'  => $wcatTerm->slug,
              'category' => '$childcat',
              'nopaging' => true,
              ));
              foreach($posts as $post) {
                  //echo $wsc->name;
              setup_postdata($post); ////set up post data for use in the loop (enables the_title(), etc without specifying a post ID--as referenced in the stackoverflow link above)
            ?>
```

But What I am getting was Categories being listed as they should but **ALL** the posts are being repeated for every sub-category.

As you can see in query I already added `'category' => '$childcat',` but still i am not getting filter applied,Please someone help me on getting this.

Complete Code

```
<?php
$wcatTerms = get_terms('menu-items', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC',  'parent' =>0));
foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
    //echo $wcatTerm->name;
    $wsubargs = array('hierarchical'=>1,'show_option_none'=>'','hide_empty'=>0,'parent'=>$wcatTerm->term_id,'taxonomy'=>'menu-items');
    $wsubcats = get_categories($wsubargs);
    foreach ($wsubcats as $wsc):
        ?><h2><?php //echo $wsc->name; ?></h2>
        <?php $childcat = $wsc->name; 
                $childid = $wsc->ID;
        ?>
        <h2><?php echo $childcat; ?></h2>
        <?php 
        $posts = get_posts(array(
      'post_type' => 'menu',
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' =>  'DESC',

      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => $wsc->taxonomy,
              'term'  => $wsc->term_id,
              'include_children' => false,
          )
      ),
      'nopaging' => true,
      ));?>
                         <div class="menu-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                         <div class="menu-title"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                        <?php //endwhile; ?>
            <?php

    endforeach;
endforeach; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one note before I start, you should not call your post type `menu`, `menu` is a reserved term, so you might run into issues with default build in functionalities. You can, however, use the plural form `menus` without having to worry about issues ragarding conflicts

As for your code, you are using invalid parameters, which is just simply ignored by `WP_Query` which in turn is the reason you are getting back all posts regardless. For custom taxonomies, you should use a `tax_query` to query posts belonging to custom taxonomy terms

The following should work: (*Note: You just need to feed the correct taxonomy name and correct term **ID** to the `tax_query` for your specific use case*)

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
      'post_type' => 'menu',
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' =>  'DESC',
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => $wcatTerm->taxonomy,
              'terms'  => $wcatTerm->term_id,
              'include_children' => false,
          )
      ),
      'nopaging' => true,
      ));
```

### EDIT

The category parameters will **not** work as you are not making use of the build in taxonomy, `category`. You are using a custom taxonomy, so to query posts from a specific term or terms from a custom taxonomy, you need to use a `tax_query` as in my sample code.

As I also stated, you need to feed the **correct** parameters to your `tax_query` as I do not know your exact setup. The `terms` parameter (by default) should be an integer value or an array of integer values of term ID's, so take that into account

Lets take an example from your code

```
$wsubcats = get_categories($wsubargs);
    foreach ($wsubcats as $wsc):
```

Inside this `foreach` loop, your `tax_query` values will be as follow:

- Your `taxonomy` value will be `$wsc->taxonomy`
- Your `terms` value will be `(int) $wsc->term_id`

### EDIT 2

Sifting through your code, there are plenty errors. I have corrected all that errors in your code and have commented on them inside the code, so make sure to check my comments. Where I have stated *to remove*, remove that specific line of code as it is not necessary. Also, I do not know if you really need empty terms, so I have left that and just build in protection to avoid bugs and errors if there are actually empty terms

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'menu-items'; // Do not use hypens in taxonomy names, only use underscores
$term_args = array(
    'hide_empty' => 0, // Why do you need empty terms? 
    'orderby' => 'ASC',  
    'parent' => 0
);
$wcatTerms = get_terms(
    $taxonomy, // Taxonomy name
    $term_args // Array of arguments to get terms by
);
// To avoid bugs and errors, run this only if we have a valid array of terms
if (    !empty( $wcatTerms ) // Check that we do not have an empty array 
     && !is_wp_error( $wcatTerms ) // Check that we do not have a WP_Error object returned
) { 
    // If our conditional check passed, then only run the following code
    foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) { // Do not use : as it is hard to debug and to read, use old style curlies
        //echo $wcatTerm->name;
        $wsubargs = array(
            //'hierarchical'=>1, // This is default, not needed and can be removed
            //'show_option_none'=>'', // Invalid parameter, where do you get this from, to remove
            'hide_empty'=> 0, // Why do you need empty terms?
            'parent'=>$wcatTerm->term_id,
        );
        //$wsubcats = get_categories($wsubargs); // Why use get_categories, get_categories uses get_terms, to remove
        $wsubcats = get_terms( 
            $taxonomy, // We have set this earlier
            $wsubargs
        );
        foreach ( $wsubcats as $wsc ) { // Again, do not use : as it is hard to debug
            ?><h2><?php //echo $wsc->name; ?></h2>
            <?php $childcat = $wsc->name; ?>
            <h2><?php echo $childcat; ?></h2>
            <?php 
               //$posts = get_posts(array( // Do not mess with $posts global, rather use $posts_array, to remove
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'menu', // Really bad name, reserved name in Wordpress
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' =>  'DESC',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, // We have defined this already right at the start
                        'terms  => $wsc->term_id,
                        'include_children' => false,
                    )
                ),
                'nopaging' => true,
            );
            $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

            // You are missing the loop here, that is why you are getting the same stuff over and over again
            if ( $posts_array ) { // Only run this if we actually have posts, if we do not have posts, we will have bugs and errors
                foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) { // You were missing this
                    setup_postdata( $post ); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT, without this, the template tags like the_content will not work
                    ?>
                             <div class="menu-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                             <div class="menu-title"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

                <?php } // endforeach $posts_array
                wp_reset_postdata(); // VERY IMPORTANT to reset the $post global to main query
            } // endif $posts_array
        } // endforeach $wsubcats
    } // endforeach $wcatTerms
} // endif check for valid array of terms
?>
```

Comment: No problem :) I am very thankful to you you made my day and saved my hair too :P the most amazing part was you edited all this using mobile thankyou very much again :)

Comment: My pleasure, I have accepted your edit as well, thanks for that. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Hey pieter you should help me with [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196704/loop-breaking-after-each-category-instead-of-posts-per-page-property) please